# Restore partitions from another pc

Tags: system-restore

I have 4 identical HP ProBook 4520s.

They come with an HP recovery partition that resets the OS (Win 7 Professional)

**One of these is completely screwed up.**

I made with `partimage` copies of the **RECOVERY**, **SYSTEM** partitions and **Master Boot Record** on a working machine but, probably due to current different partitioning just restoring partitions and MBR in the broken one does not work.

**How do I exactly (at byte precision) restore original partitioning?**

After that I would restore all recovery partitions, should it allow system recovery software to start? At the end only the Windows partition would be empty...

---

### Edit:

now I copied the `fdisk -l` out from a working machine and recreated it with `gparted` with block precision on broken one. Then will overwrite MBR and restore partitions with `partimage`.

**The recovery tool now starts but states it cannot recover partition table...**

I wish I can download an ISO image but **where**?

Comment: Have you tried CloneZilla? Maybe Acronis? (Latter is non-free.)

Comment: Do you just need the recovery partition?  AFAIK, you can't use one from another laptop because the OEM serial number is embedded in the recovery partition installation.  You're probably better off downloading a Windows 7 ISO and installing it using the serial number on the bottom of the laptop itself.

Comment: Microsoft allows you to (legally) download all Windows 7 DVDs for free - you will need a valid product key, though. Here's an unofficial list (it's a German site, but they've got links to the English versions, too): http://easytopia.de/windows-7-home-premium-und-professional-direkt-download-links/#1

Comment: @n.st: In future you can direct people to this question: [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)